# How to use Jackson's ContextualDeserializer for root values?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to implement a generic deserializer for all classes that extend from a certain abstract class or implement a certain interface. In this example I'm using interface `StringConvertible`. I need to determine the concrete type and so that I can create an instance.

An [old forum post by Programmer Bruce](http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/deserialize-with-generic-type) led me to using ContextDeserializer and it's working when the StringConvertible is a property in another class.

But when I want to deserialize the StringConvertible directly, I can't find a way to get the concrete type because the `beanProperty` parameter is `null`. Apparently that is expected, according to [this question/answer](http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/contextualserializer-and-beanproperty) at the Jackson JSON User Group: 

`The only case where property should be null is when serializing a "root value", meaning the object instance passed directly to ObjectMapper's (or ObjectWriter's) writeValue() method -- in this case there simply isn't a referring property. But otherwise it should always be passed.`

See main method below for an example of both cases:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringConvertibleDeserializer.class)
public final class SomeStringConvertible implements StringConvertible {

    private final String value;

    public SomeStringConvertible(final String value) {

        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String stringValue() {

        return value;
    }
}

public final class SomeWrapper {

    public SomeStringConvertible stringConvertible;

    public SomeWrapper() {

    }
}


public class StringConvertibleDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<StringConvertible> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private final Class<? extends StringConvertible>    targetClass;

    StringConvertibleDeserializer() {

        super(StringConvertible.class);

        this.targetClass = null;
    }

    StringConvertibleDeserializer(final Class<? extends StringConvertible> targetClass) {

        super(StringConvertible.class);

        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(final DeserializationContext deserializationContext, @Nullable final BeanProperty beanProperty)
                                                                                                                                                throws JsonMappingException {

        final StringConvertibleDeserializer contextualDeserializer;

        // ====  Determine target type  =====
        final Class<? extends StringConvertible> targetClass;
        JavaType type = beanProperty.getType(); // -> beanProperty is null when the StringConvertible type is a root value
        targetClass = (Class<? extends StringConvertible>) type.getRawClass();

        // ====  Create contextual deserializer  =====
        contextualDeserializer = new StringConvertibleDeserializer(targetClass);

        // ====  Return  =====
        return contextualDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public StringConvertible deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        final StringConvertible value;

        // ====  Create instance using the target type  =====
        if (targetClass.equals(SomeStringConvertible.class))
            value = new SomeStringConvertible(jsonParser.getText());
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        // ====  Return  =====
        return value;
    }

}

public final class JacksonModule extends SimpleModule {

    public JacksonModule() {

        super();

        addDeserializer(StringConvertible.class, new StringConvertibleDeserializer());
    }
}

public final class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JacksonModule());

        final String wrappedValueJSON = "{\"stringConvertible\":\"hello world\"}";
        final String rootValueJSON = "\"hello world\"";

        try {
            mapper.readValue(wrappedValueJSON, SomeWrapper.class);  // This works fine
            mapper.readValue(rootValueJSON, SomeStringConvertible.class);   // This causes a NPE in createContextual(...) because beanProperty is null

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** How can I get type concrete type in case of a root value? Or, if there is a better solution than this, what would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When researching the solution StaxMan proposed I stumbled upon [this Github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/165) for `jackson-databind` which addresses the exact same problem. In response, the maintainer added a method to `DeserializationContext` in version `2.5.0`:

```
This turned out relatively easy to implement, so now there is:

class DeserializationContext {
   public JavaType getContextualType() { ... }
}
which will give expected type during call to createContextual(), including case of deserializers that are directly added via annotation.
```

So to make this work in my case, I just had to change some code in the `createContextual(...)` method. I changed this:

```
   // ====  Determine target type  =====
    final Class<? extends StringConvertible> targetClass;
    JavaType type = beanProperty.getType(); // -> beanProperty is null when the StringConvertible type is a root value
    targetClass = (Class<? extends StringConvertible>) type.getRawClass();
```

To this:

```
// ====  Determine target type  =====
final Class<? extends StringConvertible> targetClass;
{
    // ====  Get the contextual type info  =====
    final JavaType type; 
    if (beanProperty != null) 
        type = beanProperty.getType();  // -> beanProperty is null when the StringConvertible type is a root value

    else {
        type = deserializationContext.getContextualType();
    }

    // ====  Get raw Class from type info  =====
    targetClass = (Class<? extends StringConvertible>) type.getRawClass();
}
```

Comment: Impressive detective work here -- thank you for sharing this!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! This was the final piece of the puzzle for me while trying to solve this particular problem: https://gist.github.com/darylteo/a7be65b539c0d8d3ca0de94d96763f33

Comment: Always using deserializationContext.getContextualType() and ignoring beanProperty also seems to work, and makes the code more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you don't.

Longer answer would explain why this is the case; but the gist is that (de)serializers need to be registered in a way that they know what they are registered for; they are not intended to be general-purpose and be told what type they are handling. They need to know it already when registered.

This may be possible by changing the way you register deserializers. Instead of using `SimpleModule`, you can implement `Deserializers`, and handle construction of deserializer with given type information.
This way there will be multiple instances of deserializer, configured with type information used for registration. This is the type expected as well.

Comment: I found a simple solution to my question. Thanks though: your solution will come in handy for more demanding cases. For anyone interested in an example, it's done in jackson-datatype-guava: [GuavaDeserializers](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/guava/GuavaDeserializers.java), which is registered inside [GuavaModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/guava/GuavaModule.java): `context.addDeserializers(new GuavaDeserializers());`

Comment: No prob, glad you figured it out. Impressive detective work too -- I had forgotten about that additional method myself. It does come in handy, need to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier way to create a generic deserializer, implements ContextualDeserializer and keep de JavaType in a variable instance :

```
public static class MappedByDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Object> implements ContextualDeserializer {
    private JavaType typeToUse;

    protected MappedByDeserializer() {
        super( Object.class );
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser aParser, DeserializationContext aContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Object lObj = aContext.readValue( aParser, typeToUse );
        // adjust your object
        return lObj;
    }

    @Override public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual( DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property ) throws JsonMappingException {
        typeToUse = property.getType();
        return this;
    }   
}
```